# Spark making a local metastore instead of storing the data in the actual mysql metastore

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, metastore

I have integrated spark with hive, hadoop with sbt build as 
**sbt/sbt -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.6 -Dhadoop-2.6.0 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver assembly
sbt/sbt -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.6 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver test**

But when I am creating a table using sparkSQL it is not creating any table in the local mysql metastore db. It's creating somewhere else. Also I have included the hive-site.xml file in conf directory of spark.

Comment: Have you configured MySQL property in your hive-site.xml file?

Comment: yes I did some hack and finally it was working fine for me . Thanks for the concern.